# Manual scroll for UltraExplorerBar Infragistics

Tags: c#, infragistics

I'm working on kiosk system which having touch screen, so I need to be able to scroll UltraExplorerBar control of Infragistics manually.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is really bad question. What is your code? What have you tried so far? Show your work here. People can't read your mind. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I asked a clear question, it was related to Infragistics Controls Library which is known Library for developers, may be you don't have experience with it..anyway thanks Soner

Comment: @kaitoked there is still more information that should be provided like what the ViewStyle of the UltraExplorerBar is.  Also why do you need to scroll it manually?  If you are not using the default scroll bar, is the Explorer bar the correct control to be using?  Note that setting the scroll position would be a feature request: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/33108.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a few months old, but infragistics' ultraexplorer bar does not directly support manually scrolling. See the below link for more information.

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/32632.aspx